# Where locally are the Azure CLI 2 authentications stored?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-cli

I am using the Azure CLI (2.0 python version) on Windows. When I login like this:

```
az login
```

It opens a browser window and logs in interactively, passing back tokens to the still running CLI process. According to the docs those temporary access tokens are stored locally somewhere, as they remain available for a while later, after the process has closed - where are the tokens stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where are the tokens stored?

You can find the **accessTokens.json** file in the folder named .azure folder in the user profile.

[image]

Also, you can rename this file before you login it again to verify it.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, you can accept it as an answer to close this case, this also might help who will find the same scenario.